# Script help string in php

Tags: php

How to make a php script that takes a argument and escapes a quote mark in every string it finds, no matter how many levels of nested array are there.

I tried something like this

```
$FileName = preg_replace("/'/", '', $UserInput);
```

but i donot want to replace the string

Comment: Can you please rephrase your post in the form of a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function recAddslashes($var){
  return is_array($var) ? array_map(__FUNCTION__, $var) : addcslashes($var, "'");
}
```

(see [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php))

Comment: Thanks.... I did not knew this addcslashes ...  but it returns the escaped character?

Comment: Well, that's what you asked. If you want to remove quotes, then just replace addcslashes with `str_replace("'", '', $var);`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but should do the trick:

```
function escape_single_quotes( $arg ){

   if( is_array( $arg ) ){

     foreach( $arg as &$k ){
        $k = escape_single_quotes( $k );
     }
   }else{
      $arg = str_replace("'","\'", $arg);
   }
  return $arg; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks John... but I donot want to replace, just want to skip it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to make the file name safe, you could employ a whitelist approach and only **allow** certain characters:

```
$Filename = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-]/', '_', $userInput);
```

The above regex will replace any character that is not a letter, a number, a dash or an underscore. Any character that is not allowed will be replaced by an underscore. Whitelisting (allowing a small list of "safe" characters) is a much safer than blacklisting (disallowing a long list of "unsafe" characters). My first assumption is that you're allowing the user to specify the name of a file on your server. However, if you are using this approach to guard against SQL injections, then you're most definitely heading down the wrong road. Prepared Statements are the only recommended way to protect your database against  SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a recursive function that loop thought each array and is the its not an array it will replace the `'` and then echo it then again loop to the next array

```
function traverseArray($array)
{
    // Loops through each element. If element again is array, function is recalled. If not,    result is echoed.
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
    if(is_array($value))
       {
           traverseArray($value);
       }else{
            $FileName = preg_replace("/'/", '', $value);
            echo  $FileName;
       }
    }
 }
```